# Could not copy the file ABCpdf9-32.dll because it was not found

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I am building a project which I have just opened the solution for and restored NuGet packages with the output:

```
All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.
Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.0781069
========== Finished ==========
```

However, when I `Build Solution`, I get several errors similar to this one:

> Error     Could not copy the file
>   "C:\Repos\myProject\packages\ABCpdf.9.1.1.9\bin\ABCpdf9-32.dll"
>   because it was not found.

I have noticed that the `C:\Repos\myProject\packages\ABCpdf.9.1.1.9\bin` folder does not exist.  How could I compile the ABCpdf NuGet package so that the build passes?

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by right clicking the solution website > `Manage NuGet Packages For Solution`, then uninstalling `ABCpdf` while remembering the installed version (in this case, 9.1.1.9).  Then, navigate to `Browse` and install the same version of the package and rebuild.